# Gvfs-mount does not work with FTP anymore

Tags: nautilus, gvfs

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 gvfs-mount does not work with FTP anymore. Trying to connect to a FTP-server using Nautilus or

```
  gvfs-mount "ftp://user@server.de/"
```

I get the following error message:

```
  Error mounting location: Error resolving '': No address associated with hostname
```

Connecting via SSH or other protocols works well. The problem occurs only with my current user. That means it can't be an issue with the FTP-Server. So I tried to delete all gvfs config files with:

```
  sudo apt-get purge gvfs
```

and after that reinstalled it. But this did not change anything.
What else could I do? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1018806
The problem results from wrong configuration of system wide proxy. If you have the same problem you can try following commands, that will reset your proxy settings to default:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts ['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port 0
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https host ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https port 0
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 0
```

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'` worked for me. It was set to `auto` before.

Comment: it backs again after reboot. How to make it works permanently?

Answer (score -1):

Tut mir leid, but that looks more like an error in host resolution than a problem with gvfs-mount. `gvfs-mount` with FTP works fine for me.

Please make sure that the regular ftp client works:

```
ftp server.com
```

Comment: The Server works well. I have more then ten FTP-Server and each works well via nautilus or gvfs mount using an other account, an other machine or an other client like FileZilla. This is not an issue with the sever.