# Cannot connect to FTP via Nautilus but FileZilla can

Tags: 14.04, networking, nautilus, proxy, ftp

I tried to connect to FTP via Nautilus on Ubuntu 14.04. When I tried the address for example, ftp://whs.servername.com, nothing happen, but I can connect it via FileZilla. If I tried with SFTP, it asked the username and passwors, but after I enter it, I got the following error message:

[image]

The ssh is work fine, and I can access another protocol like smb from Nautilus connect to server.
Anyone knows how to solve this problem? I have another Ubuntu 14.04 in MBP, but it works to connect to FTP via Nautilus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this problem by implementing a solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179516/gvfs-mount-does-not-work-with-ftp-anymore).
The problem is proxy related, and then by running the following command now, I can connect to ftp by using nautilus.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts ['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port 0
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host '' 
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https host ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https port 0
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host ''
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 0
```

To make it permanent, change the proxy configuration in system settings > networks > proxy to use manual proxy and apply system widely.